# TimeoutException when looping an list with urls

Tags: python, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver

```
Abonnenten = ["https://www.instagram.com/therock/",
          "https://www.instagram.com/selenagomez/",
          "https://www.instagram.com/wizkhalifa/",
          "https://www.instagram.com/kanyewest/",
          "https://www.instagram.com/lilmosey/"]
```

Here i got some instagram users with their url, then i would make a for loop.

```
for i in range(len(Abonnenten)):
    driver.implicitly_wait(5) #i made a wait so my browser can catch up
    driver.get(Abonnenten[i]) #that is what i thought would be correct
    # get the text from their instagram bio
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    bio = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='-vDIg']/span"))).text
```

If i start the program it loads until it comes to this part of the code. It gets the first url, waits 3 seconds or so, then loads the second url and stays at that url. Then i get this error

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxx/PycharmProjects/Website_Instagram_Browser_Scrap/main.py", line 58, in <module>
    bio = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='-vDIg']/span"))).text
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\Website_Instagram_Browser_Scrap\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: "
```

I thought adding a wait above the "bio = ..." would help, but it didnt changed anything

Comment: Did you try wait longer, and see if the exception still persists?

Comment: @wwii How is this relevant to the question? The user is receiving a timeout error from Selenium. This has nothing to do with dynamic arrays, other than the user happens to be using one in their code, but this is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Christine: OP is referring to the list as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your URLs, it looks like the error gets thrown on Wiz Khalifa's instagram (`https://www.instagram.com/wizkhalifa/`), because he does not have a bio set. This results in the `TimeoutException`, because with no bio, the element we search for is not present at all. We can add a check to see if the user has a bio at all, and just go to the next URL if they do not have one:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

# move implicit wait outside of loop, we only need to set it once
driver.implicitly_wait(5) #i made a wait so my browser can catch up

for i in range(len(Abonnenten)):
    driver.get(Abonnenten[i]) #that is what i thought would be correct

    # get the text from their instagram bio
    try: 
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        bio = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='-vDIg']/span"))).text

    # case: the user does not have a bio, so just move on to the next one
    except TimeoutException:
        continue
```

I also moved your `implicitly_wait` statement outside of the for loop, because we don't need to set that more than once.

Comment: is there a way i can contact you in privat, because you seem to always solve my problems and i don´t want to post a question everytime i am stuck

Comment: It's okay to post a question here each time you get stuck -- this will allow you to receive input from other users whose opinions & coding styles are different than mine, which helps you become a better programmer overall. Other users can see your issues too, so if they are stuck on something similar, then these questions will help them, too. As long as your questions are well-thought out, and show a level of effort made to understand the problem at hand, there is nothing wrong with posting here :)